# Open source computer vision

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am working on face recognition project and i am using opencv2.4.8. i am planning to implement face recognition using eigenface algorithm.
The thing is how to know the list of algorithm for face recognition that is present in opencv 2.4.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is simple LBP based face recognition in OpenCV contrib. It should be better than PCA (eigenfaces) in terms of sensitivity to lighting conditions. I would recommend to start from this.

Comment: Sir, i cant find LBP based face recognition in opencv contrib. OPencv contrib folder just contains contrib.hpp,detectionbasedtracker.hpp,hybridtracker.hpp,openfabmap.hpp,retina.hpp files

Comment: opencv.2.4.6\modules\contrib\src\facerec.cpp

Comment: Sir, what is that facerec.cpp is it a file which implements eigenface fisherman or lbp algorithm?

Comment: class LBPH is what you are looking for

Comment: My new doubt, I am working on face recognition using openCV.I could able to save the collected face images for training in ram memory hence i cant retrieve those images for later use. How to save the collected face images in secondary memory and retrieve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can find this information in [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at OpenCV 3.0. The change list includes face recognition functionality - http://docs.opencv.org/3.0.0/dd/d65/classcv_1_1face_1_1FaceRecognizer.html#details

Also might be worth a look at another face recognition tool, openBR - http://openbiometrics.org/. You can control the keypoint detection stage too to avoid using algorithm which breach license issues.